# How does a container view in a storyboard differ from the view of the view controller it creates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

If I use a container view to create a child view controller in a Storyboard, I get the container view as a view, but I also have the view of the new view controller. How do these two differ? Should they always be the same class and whatnot?

Answer (score 0):

The container view will be the superview of childViewController.view.